# Can I give an automatic role to the user with most coins?

Tags: node.js, json, bots, discord

I'm trying to figure out how to give an automatic role to the user with most coins on a server based on a json coins system.

Can someone tell me how I should do it? I'm a noob when it comes to these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1) Check if server has role MOST_COINS_ROLE
  -If no: Create role MOST_COINS_ROLE

Step 2) Sort the JSON data by coins highest to lowest

Step 3) Get user ID of the user with the most coins (0th index in your sorted array)

Step 4) Get the role to apply (`role = guild.roles.find(r => r.name == MOST_COINS_ROLE)`)

Step 5) Check if any user has the MOST_COINS_ROLE and isnt the one found in step 3
   -If any is found remove the role from them

Step 6) Check if the found user allready has the role -If not Apply said role to user (`guild.members.get(userId).addRole(role)`)

That should be it